# Laravel Eloquent : What is lifecycle of Eloquent model

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

With this code (theoretically)

```
class Application extends Model
{
   protected $onlineApplication;

   public function __construct(Array $attributes = [])
   {
        parent::__construct($attributes);
        if(!empty($this->id)){ //To say if model is already saved in database

            /*I fetch informations in api based on app_identifier attribute.
            Then, I can play with methodq to perform different actions. 
            For instance, self::getCredentials() according to what
            self::onlineApplication would have*/
        }
        $this->onlineApplication = $this->id;
   }

   public function getOnlineApplication()
   {
       return $this->onlineApplication;
   }
}
```

For instance, When I call `Application::all()`, it returns this result

```
 Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#2954
 all: [
   App\Application {#2955
     id: 1,
     name: "isipa.cd",
     app_identifier: "569161",
     server_id: 1,
     zone_dns: "7b716ac4ab6c1c442133cf03c475988b",
     created_at: "2018-07-29 04:59:57",
     updated_at: "2018-07-29 04:59:57",
   },
   App\Application {#2956
     id: 2,
     name: "ohelene.tk",
     app_identifier: "570161",
     server_id: 1,
     zone_dns: "090857997858a77f7ab635e47d6bcce8",
     created_at: "2018-07-30 14:12:03",
     updated_at: "2018-07-30 14:12:03",
   },
 ],
```

}

Now, what I want to know is why when with this code — below — I have this result, why `$this->id` inside constructor return null ?

```
$app = Application::find(2);
$app->getOnlineApplication(); // return null. I expected 2 as result
```

When `$this->id` or `$this->attributes['id']` can return a mapped value of Application table ?

Comment: If you present a better example of why you need the id in the constructor, I may be able to update my answer to better address your specific problem.  Setting a property to the same value as another "property" seems redundant.

Comment: Question updated !

Answer (score 2):

The Eloquent Query Builder hydrates the results with Model::newFromBuilder.

```
public function newFromBuilder($attributes = [], $connection = null)
{
    $model = $this->newInstance([], true);

    $model->setRawAttributes((array) $attributes, true);

    $model->setConnection($connection ?: $this->getConnectionName());

    $model->fireModelEvent('retrieved', false);

    return $model;
}
```

So here, you can see a new blank instance is created and then the attributes are filled with setRawAttributes.  Therefore, `$this->id` or `$this->attributes['id']` would not yet exist in the constructor.

You could rely on the retrieved event being fired to fill this property, but the code you've presented seems like there is no reason for this property to exist at all since it's equal to the id.

---

Looking at the code, it looks like the main difference between passing attributes through the constructor and through the setRawAttributes is the latter by passes mass assignment exceptions and mutations.

Answer (score 0):

Behind the scenes Laravel instantiate your model and then perform the "find" method.
Although it seems like find is a static method, it is not.

$this->id is not available at the instantiating time but only afterwards.

Even though it is not related directly to your question, it seems like you're trying to assign $this->id into $this->onlineApplication - please consider the following code which will work perfectly for your needs:

Change your class to:

```
class Application extends Model
{

   protected $appends = ['online_application'];

   public function __construct(Array $attributes = [])
   {
        parent::__construct($attributes);
   }

   public function getOnlineApplication()
   {
       return $this->online_application;
   }

   public function getOnlineApplicationAttribute(){
       return $this->attributes['id'];
   }
}
```

Or even much more simple:

```
class Application extends Model
{

   public function __construct(Array $attributes = [])
   {
        parent::__construct($attributes);
   }

   public function getOnlineApplication()
   {
       return $this->attributes['id'];
   }
}
```

Comment: Good, but `find` return an Application objet, who I think is instantiated through the constructor even if find is called statically.

Comment: I want now to know, when $this->id will be availlable ?

Comment: Tha'ts right, at the end you get the an application object, but it won't work as you plan.

I've seen that you're trying to assing $this->id into $this->onlineApplication, is that what you're looking for? And it will be available only after the find method has been executed.

Comment: Yeah... I would execute another code who need availability of `$this->id`

Comment: Please check my revised answer and see if it answers your question.

Comment: This is not what I want, I have updated my question, you can see what I want exactly